# Getting image path to use it as system tray icon

Tags: java, eclipse, image, path, system-tray

So I've been looking at many, many solutions to this "problem" but somehow nothing worked for me. I'm trying to set a system tray icon for my Java application, but no matter what I do, the icon just won't show up. Instead there's a blank spaceholder. I've tried different things to get the image path but it seems like I can't get the correct image path.

This is what the code currently looks like:

```
URL url = System.class.getResource("image.jpg");
Image img = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(url);
SystemTray mainTray = SystemTray.getSystemTray();
TrayIcon trayIconImage = new TrayIcon(img, "tray icon");
mainTray.add(trayIconImage);
```

`System.print.out(url)` returns `null`

What am I doing wrong when getting the path?
I can post a screenshot of the Eclipse folders in case that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can drag and drop the image into the package folder where your .java files are shown inside the IDE. Just drag the file from the desktop, or whatever location, and drop it into the IDE where you see your source files. after that you can simply refer to the image, "image.jpg", in your code when declaring a File or Image, or whatever class you use to make it into an object. When you export the project the image will be included so you will not have to worry about the path. Should be similar to what I did in the photo. I dragged and dropped the int.txt file into the source package.[image: The int.txt file added to the program path]

if this was helpful accept the answer.

You should be able to use this:

```
Image img = new BufferedImage("image.jpg");
SystemTray mainTray = SystemTray.getSystemTray();
TrayIcon trayIconImage = new TrayIcon(img, "tray icon");
mainTray.add(trayIconImage);
```

Basically the program can find the file because they are in the same directory which is the source packages folder.

You may want to try using the Path class and File class if you are worried about getting paths.

Comment: Oh, I think I worded the question badly. I am aware that I need to drag the image into my source folder. But my program somehow still isn't able to get the path with `getResource()`

Comment: You should not need to get the path because the file is included in the same folder as the source file. All you need to do is the edit I posted above

Comment: I changed the code. You can just instantiate an image directly. Check my edit.

Comment: That didn't work because Image is an abstract class. I used `BufferedImage img = null; img = ImageIO.read(new File("res/fio.jpg"));` and put the image file in a new folder.

Comment: If you liked my response do not forget to select my answer. I guess it cannot be of type File because your other methods need a specific type of object.